# to split the content/values from a cell in a grid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to split content/value from a cell in a grid which may contain integers or decimal values and the string is compulsory.

I have taken the the content/values from a cell from a grid in a variable.

for eg:

```
var value = (GridCustomerSupplied.SelectedCells[2].Column.GetCellContent(item) 
             as TextBlock).Text;
```

but I want to split the numeric values and string values in different variables and use them further.

Comment: This question would be more understandable if you could tell us what would be the `value` that you would get. It can be `apple123`, `a1p2p3l4e` or any other combination. What are your thoughts implementing `Split` on them!?

Answer (score 0):

You can slipt value with linq.

```
using System.Linq;

string text = from s in value
             select s
             where !Char.IsDigit(s);

var numeric = from n in value
             select n
             where Char.IsDigit(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using TryParse function. See this documentation 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/how-to-determine-whether-a-string-represents-a-numeric-value]

```
decimal i = 0;   
string s = "108";  
bool isNumeric = decimal.TryParse(s, out i);

if(isNumeric) //Your condition.
else //Your condition.
```